# Powershell - Sorting JSON data by date

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I've been looking at the Microsoft Graph API and have been trying to sort through user devices based on the Last Signin Date.

I've been able to query the api for a user and convertfrom-json into custom objects that I can iterate through. The problem I'm having, is pulling the most recent device from the list.

This is what I have, and forgive me, I'm no expert so this is likely over simplistic.. I'm trying to use sort-object, but it doesn't appear to do anything in this code.. Any advice or direction would be amazing!

```
### Authenticate ###
# Application (client) ID, tenant ID and secret
$clientId = "_REDACTED_"
$tenantId = "_REDACTED_"
$clientSecret = '_REDACTED_'
$webData = $null
$jsonWebData = $null

# Construct URI
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Construct Body
$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

# Get OAuth 2.0 Token
$tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing

# Access Token
$token = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token


### Query ###
$Headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token" }
$currentUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/_REDACTED_/ownedDevices"


    # API Call
    Write-Host "`r`nQuerying $currentUri..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $jsonWebData = Invoke-WebRequest -Method "GET" -Uri $currentUri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $Headers -ErrorAction Stop

    #Sort Data
    $webData = $jsonWebData.content | ConvertFrom-Json | Sort-Object -Property ($_.value.approximateLastSignInDateTime)
    $webdata.value.approximateLastSignInDateTime
```

Thanks,

Comment: `approximateLastSignInDateTime` is a string, so unless it is in a sortable format, you won't get the result you're hoping for.  Try casting it as a `[DateTime]` type: `Sort-Object -Property ([DateTime]$_.value.approximateLastSignInDateTime)`

Comment: What does the date look like?  PS 7 might automatically make it a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph calls support sorting the output on the server side by specifying `sortProperties`, though not all object properties support it:

```
"sortProperties": [
          {
              "name": "approximateLastSignInDateTime",
              "isDescending": false
          }
      ]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-sort

---

Another option  is using the powershell sdk/wrapper module: `Microsoft.Graph.Users`, since it automatically converts most data types into their powershell equivalent. Example cmdlet: `Get-MgUserOwnedDevice`.

```sh
Get-MgUserOwnedDevice -UserId user@domain.com -Property DisplayName,ApproximateLastSignInDateTime | 
  Sort-Object ApproximateLastSignInDateTime
```

I don't have any `ownedDevices` in my org, so you may need to find the correct property names